# Surrogate mother

Tags: halacha, technology, pregnancy-birth, genealogy

If a fetus has been formed in a mother and then deposited in a surrogate mother, who is considered the mother? In other words, does the mother's 'seed' make her the mother?

The story of Yosef and Dinah is well known. Yosef was originally in Leah and Dinah in Rochel. Because of their prayers they were 'changed' round and Yosef is considered Rochels child although made with Leah's 'seed'. Also, since it says one can always be sure who the mother is, that is why you use the mother's name, also proves that the surrogate mother is the one.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20265/sources-on-the-halachic-status-of-creating-three-parent-child

Comment: Is this possible with modern medicine? Do you move the whole placenta etc. too? How developed is this fetus?

Comment: There was a case in London not long ago where the mother had boy triplets. The father was a cohen and rabbi. The late chief rabbi who attended the bris told the mohel to also include geirus to be on the safe side. Dayan C Ehrentrau who should have been the mohel withdrew and went to Israel to discuss it with Rav Elayshiv. I dont know the outcome. Maybe someone here knows.

Comment: @cham, but did the embryos come from inside another mother or from a test-tube?

Comment: http://caselaw.lp.findlaw.com/data/law_reviews/022inter_lr_touro/vol6/part8.html

Comment: @cham, that certainly isn't standard medical proceedure.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogacy#Types_of_surrogacy

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA%3A%D7%90%D7%9D_(%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A1_%D7%9C%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%94)

Comment: יש אומרים שתמיד האשה היולדת היא האם, בין אם קיבלה תרומת ביצית מאשה אחרת, או ששימשה אם-פונדקאית עבור אשה אחרת (ראה שו"ת ציץ אליעזר ח"כ סי' מט; הרב מ. סולובייציק, אור המזרח, גיליון ה-100, תשמ"א, עמ' 122 ואילך; הגרז"נ גולדברג, תחומין, ה, עמ' 248 ואילך; הרב מ. שטרנבוך, בשבילי הרפואה, ח, תשמ"ז, עמ' כט-לו; שו"ת חוות בנימין ח"ג סי' קח, ועוד)[3].
יש אומרים שתמיד בעלת הביצית היא האם (שו"ת באהלה של תורה, ח"א סי' ע; תורת הרפואה, עמ' 173 ואילך, ועוד. וראה מאמרו של הרב א. שרמן, ישורון כא תשס"ט עמ' תקלה ואילך, בדעת הגרי"ש אלישיב)[4].

Comment: [4].
ויש אומרים שמספק שתי הנשים הן אמהותיו לחומרא (הגרש"ז אויערבאך, הובאו דבריו בנשמת אברהם מהדורה חדשה ח"ג אבהע"ז סי' א אות ו (11); הגרי"ש אלישיב, הובאו דבריו במאמרו של הרב א. שרמן, ישורון שם; הגרז"נ גולדברג, אסיא, חוב' סה-סו, תשנ"ט, עמ' 45 ואילך, ועוד)[5].

Comment: @cham I don't understand what you're trying to say in [what I've split off to be] your second paragraph. Are you trying to answer the question?

Comment: @cham, please [edit] the question to clarify the second paragraph. I, for one, don't know the story of Yosef and Dina that you're referring to off the top of my head. If the part about naming is based on an article you've read, please cite the article and summarize whatever's relevant, in its name.

Comment: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/our-antenatal-babysitter-by-the-parents-of-surrogate-triplets-1260419.html  Here is the London story I was referring to

Comment: Sorry I thought everyone knew the story. It is also brought down in my link

Comment: Overcoming odds of 1000-1, the triplets were conceived after doctors implanted two eggs taken from Mrs Cohn and fertilised with her husband's sperm. In Mrs Keep's womb, one of the eggs split into identical twins. I do realise now they were made in a test tube.

Comment: @cham, the eggs were taken from Mrs. Cohn, not embryos. They were fertilized in a test tube, not in her womb.

Comment: The association of the story of Leah and Dinah (Bereshit 30:21, see Rashi, Yonatan ben Uziel, and Ibn Ezra among others there on this) is not relevant to the subject of surrogacy. It only indicates that it is possible for the sexual characteristics of a fetus to change in the first trimester (my memory seems to be that it is the first 5 weeks after conception). The question in the 1st paragraph is dependent upon the formation of a human being as taught in Bereshit 2:7-15.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Regarding, " I, for one, don't know the story of Yosef and Dina that you're referring to off the top of my head.", See Bereshit 30:21 and Rashi, Yonatan ben Uziel and Ibn Ezra there. Please note, that story is not relevant to the subject of surrogacy asked in the title and 1st paragraph from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

*Until* recently, you knew who the mother was because it's the lady out of whom this baby came. Hence the established practice for using the mother's name when praying for someone sick.

There are many Talmudic precedents that some apply to this -- Rabbi Yissochar Frand has a tape on this that simply concludes "we're left in doubt." Do we compare it to grain that had partially grown, and then was replanted? To a pregnant woman who converts, and thus the fetus is converted *in utero*? Do we prove from the Dinah midrash that the birth-mother is halachically the mother [as the Torah implies that Leah is the mother], or do we follow the explanation found in one commentary that Shimon was allowed to marry Dinah precisely because they had different egg mothers? (It's debatable how to interpret the Dinah story.)

As for practical rulings: Rabbi Kenneth Brander has a yutorah mp3 on this: most 20th-century American poskim felt that the *birth* mother is halachically the mother, with Rabbi Aaron Soloveichik zt'l insisting that the egg is viewed by halacha as "no different than some synthetic product made in Japan."

Many Israeli poskim -- plus Rabbis Heinemann and Hopfer in Baltimore -- believe that halacha follows the *egg* mother.

In recent years, some American poskim are starting to reconsider, causing a great deal of consternation. Rabbi Ezra Schwartz has a lecture to rabbinic students at YU where he says: "when I was sitting in your chair, we were clearly told that the birth mother is the halachic mother. Now ... we're not so sure. And to make it worse, what happens if a Jewish couple in Chicago obtained a non-Jewish donor egg 30 years ago and were given the psak of R' Aaron Soloveichik that the baby did not need conversion because the host mother is Jewish ... now that baby is 30 years old and dating and suddenly today's American rabbis aren't so sure."

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, the final p'sak is not clear.  This is the subject of a chapter in the new book Headlines by R. Dovid Lichtenstein (published by OU and distributed by Menucha)  He cites support for both sides but, in the summary, he says that it is clear to him that the woman who provided the egg is considered the child's mother, and not the woman who carried the fertilized egg and delivered the infant.

Comment: The question here was about a first-half-of-pregnancy mother vs a second-half-of-pregnancy mother, not just an egg donor