# Surrogate birth, egg donations and 'Jewishness'

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth, baby-infant

This is a two part question and although nuanced in there difference - I believe there is one.

1. If a Jewish mother and father donate eggs/sperm to a non-Jewish mother is the child that is born Jewish?
2. If a surrogate carries an inseminated egg to term for a Jewish couple is the child Jewish?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59118/759